# need to remove sky background color on bar hover in apexcharts

Tags: apexcharts

Hello frontend developers.
I  just want remove this background color.I am sure about this is background color.

I am using [apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95db6.png)

thanks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMEuG.png)

I am trying this for solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide `crosshairs`. This is documented here: [xaxis – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/)

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data: [10, 20, 15]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['Category 1', 'Category 2', 'Category 3'],
    crosshairs: {
      show: false // <--- HERE
    }
  },
  grid: {
    yaxis: {
      lines: {
        show: false
      }
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts sir.Your answer is fit for my question.